# React Native Sqlite for android configuration

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native

I am playing with react native for android and i have special interest with sqlite.
I try to use the sqlite lib here [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) buy i always have BUILD FAILED when "run-android". I'm a little lost at step 4 (How to use Android) 
configuring the MainActivity
The error:

```
    E:\Documents\Visual Studio CODE\MyApp\android\app\src\main\java\com\myapp\MainActivity.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    protected List getPackages() {
              ^
  symbol:   class List
  location: class MainActivity
...
```

Have somebody a very simple sample project for android to see the correct conf?
thanks in advance.

Comment: rnpm link will do automatic linking of the package. Is it not working for Android?

Comment: Hi, i tried but no work. i think rnpm step is for ios. Msg when cmd:  
E:\Documents\Visual Studio CODE\MyApp>rnpm link react-native-sqlite-storage  
rnpm-link info Linking react-native-sqlite-storage ios dependency  
rnpm-link info iOS module react-native-sqlite-storage has been successfully linked  
rnpm-link ERR! It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: spawn UNKNOWN  
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/issues  
  
E:\Documents\Visual Studio CODE\MyApp>)

Answer (score 0):

*You are missing import statement for the List.*

import java.util.List;

@Override
    protected List getPackages() {

```
    //noinspection RedundantArrayCreation
    return Arrays.asList(new ReactPackage[]{
            new MainReactPackage(),

    });
}
```

Any java IDE has some kind of fix import function so it would automatically propose you correct solution.

Try android studio it's free and react-native automatically generate gradle configuration. All you need to do is to import your project folder with gradle files (android by default) into IDE and press ctrl+space to turn IntelliSense on.

Answer (score 0):

You should change MainAplication.java and not MainActivity.java